How to prove that a matrix smallest eigenvalue is positively correlated with some of its elements?
A block matrix：
$$\bf{J}=
\begin{bmatrix}
(\bf{A}-\bf{Q}) & (\bf{P}-\bf{K})\\
\bf{P} & (\bf{A}+\bf{Q})
\end{bmatrix},$$
where $\bf{A}$ is an $n$-dim positive definite real matrix, and its non-diagonal elements are all negative; $\bf{P}$, $\bf{Q}$ and $\bf{K}$ are $n$-dim real diagonal matrices, and their diagonal elements are all non-negative. Besides, $(\bf{A}-\bf{Q})$ is positive definite.
$\bf{To}$ $\bf{prove:}$ Under the premise that the eigenvalues of $\bf{J}$ are real numbers,  the minimum eigenvalue of $\bf{J}$ would not decrease with the increase of diagonal elements of $\bf{K}$ from zero. i.e.:
$$\frac{\partial \rm{min[eig(\bf{J})]}}{\partial \bf{K}\it{_i}{_i}}\geqslant0 , \bf{K}\it{_i}{_i}\geqslant\rm{0},\it{i}\ \rm{= 1 \dots \it{n}}$$

Some possible hints:
Given a matrix $\bf{B}$, one way to analyse the sensitivity of its eigenvalue to its element is:
$$\frac{\partial \lambda {_i}}{\partial \bf{B}\it{_k}{_j}}=u{_i}{,}{_k}×v{_j}{,}{_i}$$
, where $\lambda{_i}$ is the $\it i$th eigenvalue of $\bf{B}$; $u{_i}{,}{_k}$ and $v{_j}{,}{_i}$ are the $\it k$th element of the $\it i$th eigenvalue's left eigenvector and the $\it j$th element of the $\it i$th eigenvalue's right eigenvector, respectively.
